# how to restream rtsp h264 as "live dvr" for iOs using ffserver?

Tags: ffmpeg, wowza, ffserver

I would like to grab an existing stream from an IP-Camera delivering h264 encoded rtsp stream and **restream** it for iPhone/Ipad, where the user would have the opportunity to jump back in time for aprox. 1 minute. And later jump back to the "live" feed.

Actually I would like to do the same as in wowza (http://www.wowza.com/addons/wowza-ndvr-addon) but with ff** software.

Thank you for all your hints!

Comment: I found some comments in a sample ffserver configuration file: http://ffmpeg.org/sample.html
Does anyone have any experience with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I recall ffserver does not support http streaming protocol, so what are you restreaming the video as. I know live555 server can be configured for http live streaming.

converting to http live streaming is the only possible reason I think of that you would want to re-stream at all.

there are frameworks that can be used to play live rtsp feeds.

Dropcam is one and is based on live 555 , we have one here based on ffmpeg

https://github.com/mooncatventures-group

neither of these have the scrub back x seconds you wish, but you could easily take the extracted frames , put them into a ring buffer and play from the buffer

take a look at ffplayer-tests that records video (not audio just yet) to a new h264 mov and stores it in the photo album